# JAVA - How to get Image animated from GIF

Tags: java, android, image, gif

Hi can i get an animated image (gold.gif) with BitmapFactory, i try this line but it's not animated

image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.gold);

ps : i am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Android support GIF animation using [android.graphics.Movie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.htm) class. On every frame update you need to set Movie.setTime() with elapsed time since last frame update and then you call Movie.draw() to draw it on a canvas.

However some people report Movie class is not very reliable and undocumented. I prefer extract GIF animation frame using graphics editor such Photoshop and then put each extracted frame as separate image in /res/drawable which then I can refer with AnimationDrawable.